# Can't click on "add a comment" in First Post Review audit

Tags: feature-request, bug, review-audits

Today, I was reviewing some First Posts in the review list.

I stumbled upon [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5542035). I was about to comment on it and downvote, but... I **couldn't** comment! Clicking on the "*add a comment*" link would bring me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5542035#) which is the same page with a "#" added to the end.

> https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5542035
>   vs
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5542035#

Well, how was it **not** a surprise to see that it was an audit (after downvoting).

---

This bug might have happened because the answer was already deleted when I had the audit.

### Question

What is supposed to happen when we click on *"add a comment"* on an audit?

### Feature-Request

If this is not a bug, can it let us write a comment (that won't get saved) to make the audit less obvious?

Comment: "shouldn't an audit make you autopass if you try to enter a comment?" - I'm not convinced that it should. Commenting on genuine spam posts is pointless and doesn't help in any way. As such, commenting isn't always an appropriate action for a bad question (granted it *often* is). Additionally, there's no way for the system to know that what you write is meaningful - if comments were automatic passes you could pass any audit by commenting with "I like bananas!"... which wouldn't be a good thing.

Comment: @JonK As of now, **editing** any audit will make you autopass. (I can't find the source of that right now, but editing will make you pass as soon as you press the "**edit**" button) I thought it would be the same for "Comment", no?

Comment: But editing and commenting are very different things. By trying to edit a question/answer the system can (relatively) safely assume that you're making a genuine attempt to improve the post. It can't make that same assumption with a comment, because *at best* you're requesting that *someone else* makes the improvement.

Comment: @JonK I agree with you, I edited my question accordingly. What is it supposed to do then? Or what should it do? At least it should let me type a comment (that will be sent nowhere), because pressing the "add a comment" link would just bring me to the top of the page.

Comment: At present I believe trying to add a comment to an audit fails the audit, although I haven't tried it for some time. It may have been changed since then. Whether or not fail-by-comment is the *right* thing to do, I'd say no. I'd prefer it if comments didn't count as an action that triggered a pass or a fail, but then you'd have to decide what happens when a user hits "I'm Done" when all they did was comment.

Comment: This also happens in the Late Answer review, unable to add a comment. Ok, it was an audit on a deleted answer... couldn't act accordingly cause of that.

Comment: Should request that audits are not based on deleted content.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Well audits **are** completely based off deleted content (bad content).. I don't think this is a good request.

Comment: No, there's audits based on actual good content.