# Leaving a comment is considered as a "negative" review

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits

I received [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5548857) post through first posts review queue. However, when i left the comment to it, the engine considered my comment as "negative" review and showed up the warning [image]
Should i always press "no action needed" for the appropriate posts and then get back to them to leave the comment already outside the review queue?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268751/cant-click-on-add-a-comment-in-first-post-review-audit

Answer (score 2):

> Should i always press "no action needed" for the appropriate posts and then get back to them to leave the comment already outside the review queue?

At the moment, as the linked question from Cody shows, that's what you need to do. You can go argue in the linked question about it being whatever you think it is but until it changes, that's the way it is.

Comment: Thanks, got it. Linked page doesn't contain related discussion at first look, however when i has read completely through it i saw the point.